# Assert arrays or arrays of objects in which order doesn't matter

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, assert

I'm trying to execute some integration tests. I read from the database the values and I need to assert the content. The problem is that at every iteration the content is the same but returned always in a different order. I'm using the native module `assert` with the method `deepEqual`. Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: So your results are coming back false just because of incorrect ordering?

Comment: @NickZuber exactly

Comment: Assuming the results are coming back as an array, have you considered ordering/sorting before comparing?

Comment: Plonk 'em in an array and use `.sort()`?

Comment: actually no. I didn't considered it because it seems weird that there is no other way to make this thing happen without implementing sort functions

Comment: some array contains also objects so I should also order objects

Comment: if(!deepEqualCompare()){
   deepEqaulCompare(sortedData())
}

Comment: @Mazzy I mean you could implement your own comparison function that takes a count of the types of data returned and tries to match it against another data set, but at that point sorting would be easier

Comment: @Mazzy Could you show us an example of what kind of data you're trying to compare? (in your question)

Comment: @Mazzy you don't have to order objects, you would just need to order the keys - `Object.keys(myObj).sort().forEach(key => console.log(key))`